# Saving data to a project(But i dont want to)

Tags: netbeans

I am working with NetBeans. Output is exactly what I expect but I have some values stored in a table in XHTML. If I run the program and enter some data, the values are stored in it. If I run for the second time it shows the data in it but I don't want that data to be shown. If I press  "clean and build " in NetBeans it is clearing the data. How to clear data automatically?

I have tried in number of sites, but can't find any solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache Ant (NetBeans default), you can customize you `build.xml`. There you can clean up the table. Normally, the `build.xml` NetBeans generates has some examples, like:

```
An example of overriding the target for project execution could look like this:

    <target name="run" depends="MyProject-impl.jar">
        <exec dir="bin" executable="launcher.exe">
            <arg file="${dist.jar}"/>
        </exec>
    </target>
```

Take a look at the [Ant manual](http://ant.apache.org/manual) to search for "ant tasks" you'll need.

Comment: Hi @Jean Waghetti Thank you for your valuable response.How to override.What are the changes can i expect after overriding.Actually the same is the code in build.xml. So can you please help in providing details a step further in my problem?